# Knockout pass by reference

Tags: knockout.js, observablecollection

I am having an observable parent array and it also have child array inside some things like

```
 function locationDeviceViewModel(location) {
var self = this;
self.locationId = location.locationId;
self.locationName = location.locationName;
self.isSelected = ko.observable(location.isSelected);
self.deviceList = ko.observableArray();
location.deviceList.forEach(function (currentDevice) {
    self.deviceList.push(new deviceViewModel(currentDevice));
    promotionsViewModel.location.totalDevice.push(new deviceViewModel(currentDevice));
});

self.isSelected.subscribe(function (checked) {
    self.deviceList().forEach(function (device) {
        device.isDeviceSelected(checked);
    });
});

self.selectedDevices = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        return self.deviceList().filter(function (item) {
            return item.isDeviceSelected();
        });
    }
});
}
```

at run time i am using temp array availableDevicesOnStore which populates as following

```
  self.availableDevicesOnStore([]);
    self.retriveDeviceInProgress(true);
    self.errorFetchingDevices(false);
    self.selectedStoreIndex(currentIndex);
    self.locationsForMerchant()[currentIndex].deviceList().forEach(function (currentDevice) {
        self.availableDevicesOnStore.push(currentDevice);
    });
    self.retriveDeviceInProgress(false);
```

I am curious to know why I am  doing changes in  self.availableDevicesOnStore  and its reflecting changes in original array i.e. self.locationsForMerchant() why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default ko maintains reference

change your code to do deep copy

```
self.availableDevicesOnStore([]);
self.retriveDeviceInProgress(true);
self.errorFetchingDevices(false);
self.selectedStoreIndex(currentIndex);
self.locationsForMerchant()[currentIndex].deviceList().forEach(function (currentDevice) {

    self.availableDevicesOnStore.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(currentDevice));

});
self.retriveDeviceInProgress(false);
```

ko.toJS first convert your object to plan javascript object , removing all observable properties.
then **ko.mapping.fromJS** will map plain js object.
Note: this required ko mapping pluggin.

Answer (score 0):

When passing an object (or array) in javascript you are always passing byref, meaning even if you re assign array1 to array2, changes in array2 will effect array1. The problems are magnified with knockout as every propery is actually an object.

This can be a very frustrating issue, what I have done in the past, when I wanted to pass a ko object by value was to create a shadow copy method

something like this

```
function shadowCopy (src) {
                var ret = {};
                for (var prop in src) {
                    if (src.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                        if (ko.isObservable(src[prop])) {
                            ret[prop] = src[prop]();
                        } else {
                            ret[prop] = src[prop];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return ret;
            }
```

that is for an object mind you not an array. but you should get the gist.
There may be better solutions, but that is what I have found to work the best when dealing with objects and arrays that contain observable

Comment: Or simply use `ko.toJS`

Comment: very true, in my case toJS did not work, and I forgot about it.